# AFNetworkReachabilityManager startMonitoring

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, reachability

Do we need to call `AFNetworkReachabilityManager.sharedManager().startMonitoring()` when our iOS application comes from background?

I would like to receive network status change all the time. My concern is, whether it is mandatory to call `startMonitoring()` when the application comes to foreground and to call `stopMonitoring()` when application goes to background?